# Watir/Selenium Waiting for Ajax to refresh value of existing element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, python-requests, watir

There is no change in the page structure, only values are changing. The previous value and the new value (stored inside span tags) are both floating point numbers and it's even possible that the previous and new value be the same.

As of now, I'm trying to put a sleep and try to guess the number of seconds that best balances "waste of time" vs "enough time to load", but obviously this is really unreliable. Any better way? (I'm using Nerodia, the python port of Watir btw)

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the element to become stale? Not sure that will work but it's quick and easy to test. Is there no other indicator on the page that something is updating, even if the value remains the same? No spinner, etc.

Comment: Do you know what library is being used to do the updates? Some libraries, eg jQuery, provide functions for checking if ajax requests are occurring.